# How do I programmatically measure a purchase to Google Analytics through Google Tag Manager after a successful api POST response?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Looking through the docs for Google Tag Manager, it seems they suggest measuring a purchase by confirmation page views. Unless I'm misinterpreting this, it could be inaccurate due to a failure during redirect or artificially inflated since the link can be visited later.

So, I think it would be preferable to register, or measure, the purchase as soon as I get a successful response from my purchase POST request. Something like this:

```
function purchase(data, form) {
  fetchHelper(url, {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
    .then(json => {
      // Send info to GTM that purchase was successful
      form.reset()
      window.location.href = `confirmation.html?booking=${json.booking_number}`;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error: ', error)
      swal('Oops', error.message, 'error');
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of relying on page visits to track conversions/purchases, I would recommend firing off a GA event using Google's analytics.js. From that event data in GA, you can create a "goal" which should give you pretty clean data for the purchase/conversion.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

In GTM, you would want to set up a Tag based on a Universal Analytics type. In the options, you would set Track Type to Event then fill out your Event Tracking Parameters.

To trigger, you would want to create a new Trigger for a Custom Event. In this example, maybe the Event name is "purchase_complete". Then you could use this function to fire the trigger:

```
function fire(){
  var dataObject = {
    'event': 'purchase_complete',
    'category': 'click',
    'label': 'label_something'
  };
  if(typeof dataLayer != 'undefined'){
    dataLayer.push(dataObject);
  }
}
```

(pulled from https://jonathanmh.com/custom-javascript-trigger-functions-google-tag-manager/)

Comment: I would like to use Google Tag Manager instead for the enhanced data. I know how to do this with just Google Analytics, but not for GA in GTM.

Comment: Does firing custom events/triggers in the GTM datalayer work? https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide

Comment: That guide seems much better than the others I've seen so far. I'm going to play around with it. So I guess I could access it in my later js with `window.dataLayer`.

Answer (score 0):

**"Could be inaccurate"**
Indeed that's a common problem. If you want to achieve 100% reliability, you can rely on the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#enhanced-ecomm) with server-side code. What you plan to do should get pretty close to that. Just [push the purchase data to the dataLayer](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases) and make sure to send a hit after that (see below). One client-side solution to prevent duplicates is to save transaction IDs in a cookie and [check that cookie for past transactions before tracking new ones](https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/prevent-repeat-transactions/)

**"Suggest measuring a purchase by confirmation page views"**
It doesn't matter what you do, as long as you use a "hit" to send the ecommerce data ("payload") to GA, as by default the ecommerce data just sits on the client side and is not sent to GA. Practically, you have 2 options: pageviews or events. Typically you tend to see transaction data being sent via pageviews because traditionally it was data inserted into the confirmation page by server-side code, and you see client-side interactions such as Add To Cart sent with events because it's something handled on the frontend, but it's completely fine to send all e-commerce data with events.

Comment: You mentioned "see below" - were you going to add more details about "sending a hit"?